# Why optim() always gives me the same result?

Tags: r, statistics, statistics-bootstrap

I'm trying to use bootstrapping to calculate the confidence interval of MLE of parameter v. But in every iteration, `optim()` gives me the same result. Why is this happenning?

Here's my code:

```
# Create log-likelihood function
dofloglik = function(v, x) { n <- length(x) 
                             loglik <- n*lgamma((v+1)/2) - n*lgamma(v/2)
                                       - (n/2)*log(v*pi) - ((v+1)/2)*sum(log(1+x^2/v))
                             return(-loglik) }

# Sample
y = c(0.97, 0.41, -0.13, -0.18, 1.69, 
       0.17, -0.46, -0.65, 2.66, -0.28, 
       2.30, -0.15, 0.24, 0.43, -0.54, 
       -1.55, 2.13, -0.48, 1.24, 1.05)

# Bootstrapping
n = length(y)
sims = 10
mle = numeric(sims)
for (i in 1:sims) { 
  bs = sample(y, n, replace=TRUE) 
  mle[i] = optim(1, dofloglik, x = bs, method = "CG")$par
  print(bs)
}
mle = sort(mle)
mle
```

The output is:

```
[1]  1.05  1.69 -0.13  2.66  2.13 -0.28 -0.54 -0.65  1.69  0.43 -0.18  0.17  1.24 -0.13 -1.55  0.41 -0.18  0.24 -0.54  2.13
[1] -0.13 -0.18  2.13 -1.55 -0.65 -0.28  1.24  2.13 -0.48  2.30 -0.28 -0.54 -0.13  0.41  1.24  1.24 -0.54 -0.18  2.66 -0.54
[1]  2.30  0.43 -1.55  1.05  2.13 -0.18  1.24  0.24 -0.13  2.30 -0.48  2.66 -0.13 -1.55 -0.54 -0.13  0.43 -0.13  0.24  2.30
[1]  1.24  1.24 -0.54  2.30 -0.46 -0.65  2.13  2.66 -0.46 -0.13 -0.18  2.66  0.24 -0.48 -1.55 -1.55  1.05  0.24  0.17 -0.46
[1]  0.97  2.66  2.13  0.24 -1.55  0.43  2.13  0.43 -0.18 -1.55 -0.46  1.69 -0.48  2.66 -0.18  2.30  2.66 -1.55 -0.54 -0.54
[1]  0.41  0.43  1.24  1.69 -0.13  0.41  1.69 -0.54 -0.28  2.13 -0.46  2.30  0.17  0.97  1.24  2.30  2.66  0.43  0.43  1.24
[1]  1.24  1.24  1.05  2.66  0.17  2.13  0.17 -0.13  2.30 -0.46 -1.55 -0.28  1.24  2.30 -0.48  0.24 -0.54  0.41 -0.65 -1.55
[1]  2.66 -0.54  1.05 -0.15  0.17 -1.55  0.41  1.69 -1.55 -1.55 -0.28 -0.46 -0.48 -0.13 -0.46  0.43  1.24  0.24 -0.46 -0.28
[1]  1.05  0.24  2.13  0.97  1.69  1.05  2.13 -0.15 -0.48 -1.55  1.05 -0.15  0.43 -0.13 -0.28  0.17  2.66 -0.15  1.24 -0.28
[1] -0.48 -0.18  0.24  2.30 -0.46 -0.54  0.43 -0.54  2.66 -0.48  2.66  0.24  2.13  0.97  1.05 -0.18  2.30 -0.13 -0.46  1.24
> mle = sort(mle)
> mle
[1] 47.16466 47.16466 47.16466 47.16466 47.16466 47.16466 47.16466 47.16466 47.16466 47.16466
```

Comment: Have you checked that dofloglik is doing what you think it is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
> dofloglik = function(v, x) { n <- length(x) 
+                              loglik <- n*lgamma((v+1)/2) - n*lgamma(v/2)
+                                        - (n/2)*log(v*pi) - ((v+1)/2)*sum(log(1+x^2/v))
+                              return(-loglik) }
> 
> dofloglik(1, 1:4)
[1] 2.28946
> dofloglik(1, 2:5)
[1] 2.28946
> dofloglik(1, 3:6)
[1] 2.28946
```

That probably isn't what you intended.

The part that I suspect isn't what you want is that you split something into two lines.  Except that each line is each a valid command so R executes the first line on its own.

```
+                              loglik <- n*lgamma((v+1)/2) - n*lgamma(v/2)
+                                        - (n/2)*log(v*pi) - ((v+1)/2)*sum(log(1+x^2/v))
```

So `loglik <- n*lgamma((v+1)/2) - n*lgamma(v/2)` is run and is valid so it gets stored into loglik.  The second line `- (n/2)*log(v*pi) - ((v+1)/2)*sum(log(1+x^2/v))` is valid. It executes but doesn't store anything and since we aren't at the top level it doesn't even print.

You either need to make sure the end of your first line does't result in a complete statement (by adding minus sign to the end of that first line) or do something else to split this up in a different way.

Comment: Yes you're correct. `n*lgamma((v+1)/2) - n*lgamma(v/2) - (n/2)*log(v*pi) - ((v+1)/2)*sum(log(1+x^2/v))` is what I wanted. Thank you for the suggestion about the position of '-'. I was also wondering why when I pressed Enter in front of '-' the next line didn't give me auto indentation. So your answer solves both problems at one time.